# Macbook doesn't display screen through USB-C, only charges

Tags: display, macbook, external-display, displayport, usb-c

I've connected my screen, AOC 27P2C, to my MacBook, Pro M2 13" 2022, through USB-C. The specification of my screen says:

> "USB-C 3.2 x 1 (DP alt mode, upstream, power delivery up to 65 W)"
> ([source](https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/monitor/27p2c/specification#:%7E:text=USB%2DC%203.2%20x%201%20(DP%20alt%20mode%2C%20upstream%2C%20power%20delivery%20up%20to%2065%20W)))

Macbook is being charged, yet the screen doesn't pick up any signal.

I've tried restarting the screen and MacBook. MacBook doesn't see the screen.

- Do I need a special cable? (I'm using a Samsung USB-C cable given to their S-class Androids.)
- How do I know if the problem is in the Macbook or in the screen? (I don't have access to another screen with USB-C or a computer supporting screen via USB-C.)

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using a Samsung USB-C cable given to their S-class Androids.

Most likely this cable does not have any super-speed wires inside; only a pair of USB2 wires. The monitor should come with a dedicated full-featured C-to-C cable. Where is it?

Answer (score 1):

For video you need a USB-C type 3.1 Gen2 cable which is capable of handling 10Gbps, also known as SuperSpeed+ USB 10 Gbps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, but there's a [page on the Apple website](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-usb-c-cables-mchl447b9239/mac) that lists all the different cable types you can use with your Mac, alongside their functions, such as `Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) Cable`, `USB-C Charge Cable`, `USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter`, etc.

I've only ever had success connecting to displays through cables with ends having DisplayPort/HDMI. Using a USBC-USBC cable usually only charges my Macbook and/or the other device (though I could be wrong).